# Passing a function to jquery window load doesn't work

Tags: jquery, events, dom

```
function App(){
...
}
App.prototype.Initialize = function(){
    this.initMaps();
    this.rtspPlayer = new RTSPPlayer(); 
    this.rtspPlayer.initVXGVideoFeeds();
}

var app = new App();

$(window).load(  app.Initialize );
```

This gives this error:

```
jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: a.indexOf is not a function
```

Shoudn't it work¿? Calling the function inside an anonymous function as parameter of .load() also doesn't work. Initialize() function is never called.

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide some more code? The problem isn't in the code you've provided. It probably isn't the function's fault but what's *inside* it.

Comment: there is no `a` var visible in your code. what's `a`?

Comment: a is a variable in jquery. The other code can't possibly be the problem when the Initialzie function is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[load()](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) shorthand for `load` event has been removed from jq 3.x, you need to use:

```
$(window).on("load",  app.Initialize );
```

Otherwise, jQuery was assuming this method, [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) which then result in error you are facing on jq 3.1.1

Comment: Thats it. Thanks. I'll mark as the correct answer when stackoverflow lets me.

Answer (score 0):

If you search for `.load()` in the jQuery API you'll find two entirely different methods:

- [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) - Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.
- [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) - Bind an event handler to the “load” JavaScript event.

You want the second one which no longer exists in jQuery 3:

> version deprecated: 1.8, removed: 3.0

For the typical use case where you don't need to wait to launch scripts until all assets are loaded (no idea if it's your situation) you can do something as simple as:

```
$(app.Initialize);
```

This is a short-cut for `$( document ).ready()`. From [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3):

> Binds a function to be executed when the DOM has finished loading.